# Thread safety on spring components with couchbase

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, thread-safety

I have just rest controller, service and dao methods and . Checking if there is an existing student in the db if it is present then updating the existing object with current request values and storing in the database. But some how in multi threaded environment the values are getting overwritten for few of the records. My understanding is each thread has its own stack and variables that live inside stack which is specific to thread. In this scenario not understanding how the student object is getting overriden some times. Could any one have any idea could you please provide some inputs.

```
@RestController
public class HelloWorldController {

    @Autowired
    private StudentService service;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/student", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public String updateStudent(StudentDto studentDto) {
        service.updateStudent(studentDto);
        return "Success";
    }
}
```

...

```
@Service
public class StudentService {       

    @Autowired
    private StudentDao studentDao;

    public void updateStudent(StudentDto dto) {
        Student student = studentDao.findByStudentId(dto.getId());
        if (student != null) {
                student.setName(dto.getName());
               studentDao.update(student); // dao extends couchbaseReository
          } 
      
    }
}
```

Comment: Your service should be `@Transactional` to have things in a single transaction. If you want to prevent concurrent writes you need some locking either pessimistic (database handles locks) or optimistic (JPA handles it). Without locking if 2 requests come in, values will be overwritten and the last one wins.

Comment: Thanks for reply M. Deinum. I am using couchbase (nosql) database and using couchbase repository API.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use :

```
studentDao.save(student);
```

instead of

```
studentDao.update(student);
```

And if you want to handle task in parallel thread you can use the Annotation @Async (Spring)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. but the question is related to multi threading.. I don't need parallel tasks .. Its concurrency issue